# svn commit throws error

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

when i  try to

```
commit js code in svn(eclipse)
```

i got the following error

```
org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (400 Bad Request) in response to MERGE request for ''/arty/arty/trunk/src/main/webapp/js/user

org.tigris.subversion.javahl.ClientException: RA layer request failed
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (400 Bad Request) in response to MERGE request for '/arty/arty/trunk/src/main/webapp/js/user
```

Comment: Do you have commit rights to the repository you're trying to commit to?

Comment: yes , i did it yesterday also